# MySQL combine strings from many rows like SUM for int

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm searching function which it's working like sum.

For simple I have 4 records in table:

```
id => 1
text => abc

id => 2
text => def

id => 3
text => ghi

id=> 4
text => jkm
```

When I used SUM() for ids my result is 10, so I would like to find another function for combine texts and I want to to have "abcdefghijkm" or, is it possible, "abc.def.ghi.jkm".

I'm trying with FOR XML PATH() but it isn't working with MySQL (I can't use this... function?). Also CONCAT() isn't working too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT SUM(id), GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR '.') FROM t
```